# Generate Custom URL for links/profiles

Tags: reactjs, firebase

This is not a specific issue but I want to generate custom URLs for profiles such as localhost:3001/users/jim127. Anyone know a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) to create simple routing for your app.

In your case, you need to create a dynamic route for a specified user.

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="users" component={Users}>
      <Route path="/users/:userName" component={User}/> // dynamic route
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Next step is to get the `userName` from the URL in `User` component

```
class User extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount: function () {
    const userName = this.props.params.userName
    ...
```

and simply load any data for specified `userName`